# Can't clear filter in Excel Add-in (MS Excel 20016)

Tags: excel, add-in

I am developing an add-in for Excel 2016. I am using the following code to clear the filters of Excel:

```
        Excel.run(function (ctx) {
          var table = ctx.workbook.tables.getItem('DailyLog');
          table.clearFilters();

          for (var i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
            var column = ctx.workbook.tables.getItem("DailyLog").columns.getItemAt(i);
            column.filter.clear();
          }
        }).catch(function (error) {
          console.log(error);
        });
```

I keep getting an error: `The argument is invalid or missing or has an incorrect format.`

I appreciate if someone can offer some help on this.

Comment: Which language is the add-in being written in?

Comment: I am writing this with JavaScript and using Office.js version 1.1